# Prove $\lim_{x \to b} f(x) = c \iff \lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_k) = c $

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ and $f\colon A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. there exists $\dot{B}_r(b) \subseteq A$. Prove $$\lim_{x \to b} f(x) = c \iff \lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_k) = c \text{ for all } \{x_k\} \subseteq A \text{ with } x_k \neq b \ \forall k \text{ and } \lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = b.$$

---

I have shown "$\Rightarrow$" but the problem is "$\Leftarrow$". My idea is the following:

Let $\varepsilon > 0 $. Let $g:A \cup\{b\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & x \in A \\ c & x =b \end{cases}$$

If one could show that $g$ is sequentially continuous at $b$ then $g$ is continuous at $b$ and therefore we can pick a $\delta > 0 $ s.t. $0 < \Vert x-b\Vert < \delta \implies \vert g(x) - g(b) \vert = \vert f(x) - c \vert < \varepsilon $.

The trouble is showing sequentially continuous at $b$. Is it possible to get this since we only have the desired convergence for sequences with $x_k \neq b $. And if so, how? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think it is easier to prove the contrapositive. If $\lim_{x\to b} f(x)\ne c$, then $\exists\varepsilon>0\forall\delta>0\dots$. Now construct a sequence $x_k$ be taking suitable $\delta$.

Comment: This result is due to Heine. It is worth mentioning that $\Rightarrow$ is trivial and always holds. However, without the Axiom of Choice (or weaker form, Axiom of Countable Choice), it is impossible to prove the $\Leftarrow$ direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is the proof in the context of metric spaces.

**Proposition**

Let $(X,d_{X})$ and $(Y,d_{Y})$ be metric spaces, $f:X\to Y$ a function and $E\subseteq X$ s.t. $x_{0}\in X$ is an adherent point of $E$ and $L\in Y$. The following statements are logically equivalent:

(a) The limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $x_{0}$ along $E$ is $L$.

(b) For every sequence $x_{n}\in E$ which converges to $x_{0}$ according to $d_{X}$, the sequence $f(x_{n})$ converges to $f(x_{0})$ according to $d_{Y}$.

**Proof**

Let us prove $(a)\Rightarrow(b)$ first.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists $\delta_{\varepsilon} > 0$ s.t. for every $x\in E$ one has that
\begin{align*}
d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow d_{Y}(f(x),f(x_{0})) < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

On the other hand, for every $\delta_{\varepsilon}$, there corresponds a $n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
n > n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow d_{X}(x_{n},x_{0}) < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow d_{Y}(f(x_{n}),f(x_{0})) < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

hence $f(x_{n})$ converges to $f(x_{0})$, and we are done.

Let us prove now the implication $(b)\Rightarrow(a)$.

We shall do so by contradiction.

Let us assume that $f(x)$ does not converge to $f(x_{0})$.

Hence we conclude there is a $\varepsilon > 0$ s.t. for every $\delta > 0$ there corresponds a $x_{\delta}\in E$ satisfying
\begin{align*}
(d_{X}(x_{\delta},x_{0}) < \delta)\wedge(d_{Y}(f(x_{\delta}),f(x_{0})) \geq \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

Thus if we take $\delta = 1/n$, we conclude that $x_{n}\to x_{0}$ according to the squeeze theorem.

This means there exists a sequence $x_{n}$ which converges to $x_{0}$, but $f(x_{n})$ does not converge to $f(x_{0})$.

This contradicts our assumptions.

Hence the proposed claim is true.

Hopefully this helps!